# Binary classification using Keras always give wrong predictions: The acc is always 0.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hi~ I am using Keras to make a simple binary classification. And I am using TF as backend.

I checked:

- data shuffle: I set the param in model.fit() shuffle = True
- network structure: The NN take a vector with 1024 elements and makes a prediction 0 or 1.

ENV: tensorflow 1.13.2 Ubuntu 16.04 python3

But the output is still wrong. The acc is always 0.5.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda, Conv2D, Reshape, MaxPool2D, Average, Dropout, Concatenate, \
    Add, Maximum, Layer, Activation, Conv1D, TimeDistributed, GlobalAvgPool2D
import numpy as np


class Test(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,attention_sz,dropout_rt, name=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(name=name)
        # here we define the layer:
        self.fc = Dense(attention_sz,input_dim = attention_sz ,activation='relu')
        self.fc2 = Dense(attention_sz, activation='relu')
        self.fc3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

        self.dp = Dropout(dropout_rt,input_shape=(attention_sz,))
        self.dp2 = Dropout(dropout_rt,input_shape=(attention_sz,))


    def call(self, inp):
        # here we get the segmentation and pose
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            print("~~~~~~~~~~~")
            x = self.fc(inp)
            print(x.shape)
            z = self.dp(x)
            print(z.shape)
            x = self.fc2(z)
            print(x.shape)
            z = self.dp2(x)
            print(z.shape)
            y = self.fc3(z)
            print(y.shape)
        return y 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model  = Test(1024, 0.05)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    x = np.round(np.random.normal(1.75, 0.2, size=(10000, 1024)), 2)
    x2 = np.round(np.random.normal(100.75, 0.2, size=(10000, 1024)), 2)
    labels = np.zeros((10000, 1))
    labels2 = np.ones((10000, 1))

    x_t = np.row_stack((x, x2))
    labels = np.row_stack((labels,labels2))
    print(x_t.shape)
    print(labels.shape)
    model.fit(x_t, labels, shuffle=True, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    x = np.round(np.random.normal(1.75, 0.2, size=(1, 1024)), 2)
    y = np.round(np.random.normal(100.75, 0.2, size=(1, 1024)), 2)
    res = model.predict(x)
    print(res)
    print(res.shape)
    res = model.predict(y)
    print(res)
    print(res.shape)
```

output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/frank/Desktop/mesh-py3/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
2020-05-06 19:00:58.440615: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-05-06 19:00:58.616327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-06 19:00:58.617158: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x55201b0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2020-05-06 19:00:58.617175: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-05-06 19:00:58.636996: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2592000000 Hz
2020-05-06 19:00:58.637508: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x558add0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-05-06 19:00:58.637523: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-05-06 19:00:58.637876: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.095
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 7.77GiB freeMemory: 7.06GiB
2020-05-06 19:00:58.637892: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-06 19:00:58.639694: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-06 19:00:58.639708: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2020-05-06 19:00:58.639713: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2020-05-06 19:00:58.639923: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6868 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
Epoch 1/10
2020-05-06 19:00:59.495123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 148us/sample - loss: 8.0497 - acc: 0.4997
Epoch 2/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 98us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 99us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 80us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 81us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 80us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 89us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 83us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 78us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2s 79us/sample - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
[[0.]]
(1, 1)
[[0.]]
(1, 1)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same code is giving me 0.9857 after 1 epoch

Comment: wow! why? it is quite weird.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/qOABle.jpg <-- look

Comment: I am using `tensorflow-cpu==1.15.0` and `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: tensorflow 1.13.2 Ubuntu 16.04 Keras 2.2.4

Comment: Try `pip install tensorflow-cpu==1.15.0` and then try to run. If it gives a better accuracy that create an issue on their Github page.

Comment: Hi @Pygirl I successfully make it using tf-gpu==1.15.0. But why?

Comment: Raise an issue there.

Comment: Hi I just raise a issue at github. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39223

Comment: @Pygirl Hi~ I met another problems here. Can you help me if it is possible? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/61724827/13482179

Answer (score 1):

Root-cause of the issue is related to numerical instabilities of sigmoid activation in the final layer of model when used with tensorflow-cpu version.I changed two lines in your code as follows and got the similar as you get with TF1.15. Please check the [gist here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/39223_cpu.ipynb).

```
self.fc3 = Dense(1) #, activation='sigmoid'

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss=loss, #'binary_crossentropy'
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I used your code as it is with tensorflow-gpu version of TF1.13.2, then I noticed similar results as you have seen with TF1.15. Please note that the cpu and gpu versions uses different libraries for optimum computational time. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/dfbb1b550478e5b171e407aec7b32af5/39223_with_gpu.ipynb) is a gist with TF1.13.2-gpu version. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It means your Network isn't learning. In that case you can try the followings:

1. change learning rate. make it smaller till you reach 1e-6. if still not learning problem is somewhere else.
2. try different optimizers. I have experienced alot that for the same network but different data I had to change the optimizer to converge.
3. check the doc of the API for the type of your labels. It happens alot that changing the data type effects learning.